# Error object when received by useQuery hook does not return the correct error name

Tags: error-handling, graphql, apollo-client

I throw an error from my back-end and would like to have both message and name as properties of that error:

```
const error = new Error(`no payments made by the customer`);
error.name = "nothingToRefund";
throw error;
```

On frontend I use Apollo Graphql's useQuery hook:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(overpaymentEligibleOfRefund, {
    skip: !customerData?.me.id,
    variables: { customerId: customerData?.me.id },
    fetchPolicy: "network-only"
  });
```

When I console log `error.name` on front-end I just get default Error, and my name that I gave to the error is not reflected.

Comment: raw network response?

Answer (score 1):

error object returned by useQuery hook has the following keys:
["graphQLErrors", "networkError", "message", "extraInfo"]

Finally, I found name property under graphQLErrors array:

`error?.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.name`